# UPDATE on multiple TABLE SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to decrease by 2 points the notes of name : Pardin.

I don't know how to do the join with update.

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT 
(
    Mat VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Firstname CHAR(20),
    DateNais DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT NameFirUn UNIQUE (Name, Firstname),
)

CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
    CCode INT,
    Mat VARCHAR(20),
    Note FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
    Edate DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTE CHECK (Note BETWEEN 0 AND 20),
    FOREIGN KEY (Mat) REFERENCES STUDENT(Mat),
)
```

I make this :

```
UPDATE TEST E1
JOIN STUDENT E2 on E1.Mat = E2.Mat
SET E1.Note -= 2 
WHERE STUDENT.Nom = 'Pardin'
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server  ?????

Comment: I use sql-server

Comment: Looks good to me. Whats the problem?

Comment: Sounds like there are simply no matching records that match on `mat` or there is no record with `name=Pardin`. I suggest you _not_ use `float`. Use `INT` or `DECIMAL` instead.

Comment: I have this message: 0 lines affected

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (in SQL Server):

```
UPDATE T 
SET T.Note = T.Note - 2
FROM TEST T 
INNER JOIN STUDENT E2 on T.Mat = E2.Mat AND E2.Nom = 'Pardin'
```

Comment: I have this message: 0 lines affected

Comment: Check your where clauses and data in the tables. We have no chance to know data of your tables.

Comment: I inserted this insertion request :INSERT INTO STUDENT(Mat, Name, Fistname, DateNais)
VALUES('std224','Pardin','Hugo', '8-1-86')

Comment: Then there were no matching rows. That means that either (a) there is no `student` with `Name` 'Pardin' or (b) that there is a `student` with `Name` 'Pardin' but that `student`'s `Mat` doesn't match any `Mat` in `test`. That is literally the only explanation for the behaviour you're seeing, so double-check your data. Does `SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE Name = 'Pardin'` return a row? If it does, what is the row's `Mat` set to, and does it exist in `Test`?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql

```
UPDATE TEST 
JOIN STUDENT  on TEST.Mat=STUDENT.Mat  AND STUDENT.Nom = 'Pardin'
SET TEST.Note =  TEST.Note -2
```

in sql server

```
UPDATE TEST 
SET TEST.Note =  TEST.Note -2  
FROM TEST
JOIN STUDENT on TEST.Mat=STUDENT.Mat AND STUDENT.Nom = 'Pardin'
```

Comment: There is no "Note" column for STUDENT table.

Comment: It strange, I still have 0 lines that are affected. Yet the request seems to me right

Answer (score 0):

Here is a how you can do your `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
Mat VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Firstname CHAR(20),
DateNais DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT NameFirUn UNIQUE (Name, Firstname)
);

CREATE TABLE TEST (
CCode INT,
Mat VARCHAR(20),
Note FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
Edate DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTE CHECK (Note BETWEEN 0 AND 20),
FOREIGN KEY (Mat) REFERENCES STUDENT(Mat)
);

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES
('SQL-Server', 'Pardin', 'Student1', GetDate()),
('Delphi', 'Pardin', 'Student2', GetDate()),
('French', 'NotPardin', 'Student3', GetDate()); -- Not Pardin here

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
(1, 'SQL-Server', 13, GetDate()),
(2, 'Delphi', 17, GetDate()),
(3, 'French', 15, GetDate()); -- Not pardin here
-- See your data first
SELECT * 
FROM TEST T JOIN STUDENT S ON T.Mat = S.Mat;
-- Update the data in the TEST table
UPDATE T
SET T.Note = T.Note - 2
FROM Test T JOIN STUDENT S ON T.Mat = S.Mat WHERE S.Name = 'Pardin';
-- See the final results
SELECT * 
FROM TEST T JOIN STUDENT S ON T.Mat = S.Mat;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HYKGZ96769)**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution using nested query:

```
update test
set note -=2
where mat in (select mat from student where Nom='Pardin')
```

If the subquery exactly returns one record, you can replace `=` with `in`